# Which is faster? \s vs \s+

Tags: java, regex

Just a quick question I had involving the speed of processing of regex, in Java primarily.

Although I know there is most likely an insignificantly small difference, it is still interesting to know.

Which operation would be faster on some string such as `"test test     test    test   "`:
`string.replaceAll("\\s", "");` or `string.replaceAll("\\s+", "");`

The first operation has a less complicated regex, but makes more replacements, and the second is vice versa.

Which would be (so incredibly slightly) faster?

Comment: You know you are able to check this yourself, right?

Comment: [The one without regex](http://ideone.com/uIJNAo), I guess.

Comment: I would bet my 3 cents on `\s+`. But it would depend on the string you are matching. If you have only single spaces, intuitively only `\s` should be faster.

Comment: The one that is faster is the one that works. Correctness before optimization (which may be unnecessary).

Comment: this particular one? Well what about using simple `string.replace(" ","")`?

Comment: In my experience, `\s+`, but if it matters to you, time it for your use case and check

Comment: Have you tried something to answer your own question?

Comment: `replace(" ","")` does _not_ do the same: `'\s'` is _any whitespace_, not just the space character.

Comment: I think you should write the one which is clearest to you. For me that would be `"\\s+"` to indicate any number of spaces should be removed, but it is to taste.  The performance is highly unlikely to matter and if it does you are probably better off not using a regex at all.

Comment: I would also venture to guess that `\s+` will be slightly faster. If you're using `\s`, then after every replace the RegEx engine does, a new string is likely built, and building strings takes time. On the other hand, `\s+` matches multiple spaces, so sequences of multiple spaces can be replaced at once before a new string would be built. That said, the overall difference in total time would be so minor that it probably wouldn't matter much in production code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The efficiency of \s+ would be better in terms of time and space complexity because:

1. \s searches for the first space and shifts the subsequent characters left.
2. Then it checks for the next position and finds a new space and repeats step 1.
3. \s+ checks all the consecutive spaces at once and shifts all the characters n(number of consecutive whitespaces) left at once thus reducing the complexity

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

using **\\s+** regex would be faster approach

For a string of 25 fixed length,  **1000000** iteration took -

```
 \\s = 1850479750 nano second
\\s+ = 1206349361 nano second
```

But for better performance, if you need to use same pattern in more than one replacement operation, you should Compile the pattern once then use the pattern object

```
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
```

Otherwise each time 
String.replaceAll() is invoked, it do the same pattern compilation in every invocation -

```
2217
2218    public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
2219        return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
2220            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
2221    }
```

Comment: I would mark your answer correct as well if I could mark multiple answers! Thanks for the informative test.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is actually [critical-path](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) in your code, then the one that performs fewer operations is likely to be faster, but if you can reuse a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that *should* be even faster.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
// ...
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
str = m.replaceAll("");
```